# Magento - Getting the title of a cms static block from it's block_id?

Tags: magento

I'm inserting a cms static block via a widget instance - and I'd like to output the static block title as well as it's content, from within my widget template. The default template (app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml) simply has:

```
<?php echo $this->getText(); ?>
```

I changed that to *getData()* instead to see what it was possible to grab, which is the following:

```
[type] => cms/widget_block
[block_id] => 11
[module_name] => Mage_Cms
[text] => blahblahblah
```

So I'm guessing the only way is to use the block_id to get the title, but can't quite figure out how. I can grab the block_id from there with *$this->getBlockId()* - but then how do I use that to get the title?

I thought the following might work but it doesn't:

```
$blockid = $this->getBlockId();
$blocktitle = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($blockid, 'block_id')->getTitle();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems the following works:

```
$blockid = $this->getBlockId();
$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockid);
echo $block->getTitle();
```

Always helps to write out a question here, half the time seeing it written helps me find the answer myself!

Answer (score 1):

If you have several stores and you want for the store you are on, it is like that:

```
$title = Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->load($blockId)
    ->getTitle();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to create a function for it on your block:

```
public function getContactWidgetHtml()
{
    $result = '';

    $widget = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load(14);

    if ($widget && $widget->getId()) {
        $widgetBlock = $this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(
                $widget->getType(),
                $widget->getTitle(),
                $widget->getWidgetParameters()
            );

        if ($widgetBlock) {
            $result = $widgetBlock->toHtml();
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

And then display it in your template using:

```
echo $this->getContactWidgetHtml();
```